# Combined "if $_SESSION with <script> not working working

Tags: javascript, php

I have a script that needs to execute on page load based on a session value but it is not working (500 error in dev console).

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION["CONNECTION_CHECK"] == "1") {
echo "<script>";
echo "document.getElementById("CONNECTION_OK").style.display = "block";";
echo "</script>";
}
?>
```

I tried with and without "echo" but the result is the same.

I have another piece of code that is kind of similar and it does work.

```
<?php if ($output == 1) : ?>
<script>
document.getElementById("CONNECTION_OK").style.display = "block";
</script>
<?php endif ?>
```

I tried modifying this to include the if statement but it didn't work.

```
<?php if ($_SESSION["CONNECTION_CHECK"] == "1") : ?>
<script>
document.getElementById("CONNECTION_OK").style.display = "block";
</script>
<?php endif ?>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code.

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION["CONNECTION_CHECK"] == "1") {
echo "<script>";
echo "document.getElementById('CONNECTION_OK').style.display = 'block';";
echo "</script>";
}
?>
```

you cannot put double indention in double indentation block.

Comment: Thank you so much, I did not know that. Such an easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use double quotes inside double quotes, you must escape them with an Slash ():

```
if ($_SESSION["CONNECTION_CHECK"] == "1") {
    echo "<script>";
    echo "document.getElementById(\"CONNECTION_OK\").style.display = \"block\";";
    echo "</script>";
}
```